# iOS AVAudioPlayer - how to set file path to the pathForResource

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

i want to play small mp3 file when button is clicked. but not sure how to set the mp3 file in setPathForResources

Here My Code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("/sounds/superman", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    @IBOutlet weak var PlaySlow: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func PlaySlowAction(sender: UIButton) {
      audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

I have added the `sounds` folder to the project using just drag and drop. but when i click button im getting this error.

`audioPlayer.play() Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1,address=0x1c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `sounds/` in your path. Just the filename. e.g.

`var coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("superman", ofType: "mp3")!)`

Also `fileURLWithPath` takes a URL, not a string. You need to convert your `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("superman", ofType: "mp3")` to a string first using `NSURL(string:)`.

This is the full setup:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("superman", ofType:"mp3")
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
player.prepareToPlay()
player.delegate = self
player.play()
```

Comment: What line do you get the crash on?

Comment: you mean like this  NSURL(String: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("superman", ofType: "mp3")!) ?

Comment: Yes. pathForResource returns a string. Your audio player take a url (contentsForFileWithURL I think). You need to convert your string to a URL and then give that URL to initialise your audio player. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/KieranMcGrady/KMMediaControls/blob/master/KMMediaControls.m). It's in objective-c but it might help with explaining it.

Comment: im getting the error at `if(audioPlayer.data == nil) Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1,address=0x8)` i modified the code as Michael explained.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full setup. After that call ```audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()``` and then ```audioPlayer.play()```.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked. but for the `player.delegate = self` got error Type PlaySoundsViewController does not  conform to protocol 'AVAudioPlayerDelegate' so i removed it.

Comment: You need to implement the delegate (optional). Next to your superclass put ```, AVAudioPlayerDelegate```. It's optional though and perfectly fine to leave out.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a couple necessary steps in your "`PlaySlowAction`" method:

```
@IBAction func PlaySlowAction(sender: UIButton) {

    // if the audioPlayer hasn't been set to any sound file yet, 
    // load it up...
    if(audioPlayer.data == nil)
    {
        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound, error: &error)
        if let actualError = error {
            println("An Error Occurred: \(actualError)")
        }
    }
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()

}
```

Comment: now im getting that error in `if(audioPlayr.data == nill) Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1,address=0x8)` am i setting path correctly?

Comment: I added an error check to the line of code that loads the audio player, just in case something is wrong with the file URL or with the data.